# How to get own vm name in guest environment

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vmware-tools

I want to change VM setting in my own guest VM.
I can connect to vCenter but I'm not detecting my own VM.

What is a simple way to get the VM name?

Comment: I want to get own vm name. This environment is In VM. I know vCenter information but I don't know own VM information.

Comment: Can I get own VM name by vmware-toolbox-cmd? This environment is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can use a simple Powershell command like so:

> get-vmmserver localhost | get-vm "vmname" | select Name, ComputerName,
>   HostName | format-list

Answer (score 0):

PowerCLI allows you to do this simply with:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server vcenterservername.fqdn
Get-VM -Name vmname
```

You can also just connect to the web client and perform a search at: https://vcenterservername.fqdn/